# Android Build > Code Generation and Runtime option > Enable Startup tracking?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a Xamarin forms app that I would like to send to the Google Play store.

I see this option:

> Android Build > Code Generation and Runtime option > Enable Startup
>   tracking

Is that something that people normally select when working with XF and deploying to the Play Store?

Comment: https://instabug.com/blog/how-to-release-xamarin-app-ios-and-android/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows

Comment: No .Its for AheadOfTime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377106/enable-aot-in-xamarin-for-android-visual-studio